# Crear consulta MongoDb con Python2.7

Tags: python, json, mongodb

tengo la siguiente duda, estoy construyendo una consulta que realiza una inserción masiva en mongodb, pero parte de los datos son traídos desde una función.

La siguiente es la función que uso, mi problema quizás es con el return

```
def formula(df,W, tipo):
    LEQ = []
    pd=data(df,W) 
    for index,info in pd.iterrows():
        bands = info[2:]
        LEQ.append(10**(NivelesPd(bands)/10))
    level = round(10 * math.log10(sum(LEQ)/len(LEQ)),1)
    maxNps = round(10 * math.log10(max(LEQ)),1)
    minNps = round(10 * math.log10(min(LEQ)),1)

    metrica = "'" +tipo +"' : "+ str(level) +", '"+tipo+"_MAX' : " + str(maxNps) + ", '"+tipo+"_MIN' : " + str(minNps)
    return  metrica
```

Una vez que obtengo la información de la formula, realizo un ciclo "for"

```
for index, df in grouped_per_time:
   data= { 'ids' : str(ids), 'time' : str(index), 'tzone' : str(tzone) +", "+ formula(df,A, tipo='1') +"," + formula(df,B, tipo='2')+"," + formula(df,C, tipo='3') }
   #realiso el insert en mongo
   pd.save( data)
```

La inserción se realiza bien, pero la concatenación que hago con la función, me coloca todos los datos de las formulas como uno solo

```
{'tzone': "-3, 'a' : 30.5, 'amx' : 30.5, 'amn' : 30.5,'c' : 29.9, 'cmx' : 30.0, 'cmn' : 29.9,'z' : 30.9, 'zmx' : 30.9, 'zmn' : 30.9", 'ids': 'b827', 'time': '1534250153'}
```

Como ven los siguientes datos que están entre comillas y deberían estar por separados

'tzone': **"-3, 'a' : 30.5, 'amx' : 30.5, 'amn' : 30.5,'c' : 29.9, 'cmx' : 30.0, 'cmn' : 29.9,'z' : 30.9, 'zmx' : 30.9, 'zmn' : 30.9"**

Los datos deberían quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
{'tzone': '-3', 'a' : 30.5, 'amx' : 30.5, 'amn' : 30.5,'c' : 29.9, 'cmx' : 30.0, 'cmn' : 29.9,'z' : 30.9, 'zmx' : 30.9, 'zmn' : 30.9, 'ids': 'b827', 'time': '1534250153'}
```

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres a que deberían estar por separados. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de un return correcto?
¿Puede que la comilla antes del -3 de tzone sea la causante de todo?

Comment: La inserción de los datos me coloca entre comillas la información obtenida de las función formula, no se si sera la forma correcta de crear la concatenación.

Comment: podrías hacer lo siguiente y decirme si el error persiste? : `data = dict()` 
`data['ids'] = str(ids)
data[ 'time'] = str(index)
data['tzone'] = str(tzone) +", "+ formula(df,A, tipo='1') +"," + formula(df,B, tipo='2')+"," + formula(df,C, tipo='3')`

Comment: El diccionario te imprime las cosas correctamente, le tienes dicho que todo lo que vaya después de tzone esté como string:
`'tzone' : str(tzone) +", "+ formula(df,A, tipo='1') +"," + formula(df,B, tipo='2')+"," + formula(df,C, tipo='3')` ¿Podrías mostrar qué devuelve estos comandos? 
`str(tzone)`

`formula(df,A, tipo='1')`

`formula(df,B, tipo='2')`

`formula(df,C, tipo='3')`

Comment: Te refieres solo a ejecutar las formulas?

Comment: me refiero a que quiero saber qué no se qué almacena esas variables o qué te devuelve la fórmula, quiero descartar que te devuelva algo raro. Puedes hacer un print()

Comment: La formula me devuelve lo siguiente set(["'A' : 30.5, 'A_MAX' : 30.5, 'A_MIN' : 30.4"])

Comment: ¿Seguro? porque en tu diccionario no aparece eso...

Comment: Específicamente es: set(["'a' : 30.5, 'amx' : 30.5, 'amn' : 30.4"]) solo es lo que me retorna la función formula